# структура в импортируемом пакете

Tags: golang

Как вызвать метод из шаблона, если структура данных находится в импортируемом пакете а сам метод в мейн функции?

Я делаю что-то типа `MyIndex *mystruct.Index` но шаблонизатор меня посылает подальше.

[Исходник](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e77c020d40f745bfa76a81678292be37)  максимально упростил.

#### main.go

```
package main

import (
        "gofail/lib"
        "html/template"
        "net/http"
        //"os"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        test := mystruct.Person{"Andrey", 11}
        indexTemplate := "template/index.html"
        tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(indexTemplate)                                                                                                                                      
        if err != nil {                                                                                                                                                                      
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)                                                                                                                   
                return                                                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                                                                    

        if err := tmpl.Execute(w, test); err != nil {                                                                                                                                        
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }

}

type libStruct struct {
        MyIndex *mystruct.Index
}

func (v *libStruct) MyMethod() string {
        return "omgs"
}

func main() {
        r := http.NewServeMux()
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/template/"))
        r.Handle("/template/", fs)
        r.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
        server := &http.Server{
                Addr:    ":8085",
                Handler: r,
        }
        err := server.ListenAndServe()
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

}
```

#### struct.go

```
package mystruct

type Person struct {
        Name string
        Age  int
}

type Index struct {
        Distro string
}
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
<h1>Homepage</h1>

<div>{{.Name}}</div>
<div>{{.MyMethod}}</div>
<p>HI!!!</p>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы суёте значение типа `mystruct.Person` в шаблон, но у этого типа нету метода `MyMethod`. Чего вы ожидаете?

Comment: Спасибо, значит тип  должен быть  обязательно Person ?  верно ?

Comment: А  для   добавления определённых методов использовать вложенные структуры ?

Comment: Почему Вы говорите про метод, когда, по факту, -- это свойство?

Comment: [Посмотри пример моего модуля обертки для рендера шаблонов](https://github.com/spouk/spoukrender/blob/master/spoukrender.go) Смотри, есть мультиплексор + обработчик + шаблон(ответ на запрос обработчиком) + контекст. Для ясного понимания работы шаблонов и передачи в шаблоны данных, поработай просто с ними, без привязки к серверу и запросам. Делай простой рендеринг с добавлением данных и функций туда, когда ясно уяснишь для себя как происходит это вся механика, можешь переходить к мультиплексору и обработчикам с сохраняемым контекстом при запросах.

Comment: @Ainar-G тут вам автор ответил, но без упоминания, так что уведомление не пришло. Посмотрите. :)

Comment: @OlegTsim Я не понимаю, чего вы хотите от кода. Поле `Name` есть только у `Person`, а метод `MyMethod` - только у `libStruct`. Либо добавьте поле `Name` в `libStruct`, либо определите `MyMethod` для `Person`.

Comment: Спасибо , я  разобрался уже.  Большое всем спасибо. Я  не мог понять саму работу шаблонизатора и его привязку  к структурам. Ещё  раз  огромное всем спасибо, постараюсь в следующий раз более  детально разобраться в вопросе самому , прежде чем задавать  вопрос.

Comment: Если вам понятна работа шаблонизатора и его привязка к структурам, то опубликуйте ответ. Другим тоже интересно.